# call different phtml file from cms in different website

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using CMS/pages in magento. I am calling phtml file from cms/pages/homepage.

CMS pages is common for all the websites that are created in that system. (I guess correct me if i am wrong)

How can i call different phtml files based on which website is loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different CMS pages for different store views (and thus websites). Check the Magento wiki if you don't know how to work with it's admin panel.

Comment: can u guide me to this specific problem given in magento wiki ?

Comment: @BSThakrar http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/multi-store_set_up/how_to_make_multi-lang_cms_pages